# How to replace text in get-mailboxfolderstatistics without breaking the array

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

The Exchange PowerShell commands for Mailbox Folder Statistics and Permissions are disjointed and require you to massage data to take statistics and make them usable as variables for removing folder permissions.

I'm trying to use the replace commands in PowerShell to manipulate the values without breaking the array itself.

I've tried various ways of using the -replace command to handle this as it has been unsuccessful.

I'm trying to use code similar to this:

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity jon@towles.com | Select Identity |  ForEach-Object { $_."Identity" -replace '.com','.com:'}
```

When I use the replace function, it breaks the array so we no longer see headings and cannot use it with stuff like `foreach-object {Remove-MailboxFolderPermissions -identity $_.identity -user testuser}`

I expect that the replace function will still keep the data layout.

Comment: $_.identity is what breaks the heading because you are dereferencing a property. You can skip the foreach all together and just use a calculated property in your select-object

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This was the fix:$folders = get-mailboxfolderstatistics -Identity $user | Where-Object {($_.FolderPath -ne "/Top of Information Store" -and $_.FolderPath -ne "/Recoverable Items" -and $_.FolderPath -ne "/Deletions" -and$_.FolderPath -ne "/Purges" -and $_.FolderPath -ne "/Versions")} | Select-Object -Property @{ Name = 'FolderPath'; Expression = { $_.identity -replace 'test.com','test.com:' -and -replace '?','\'}}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain your psobject structure, you need to avoid dereferencing properties or expanding properties. In your case, you can use a calculated property in your `Select-Object` command.

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity user@domain.com |
    Select-Object @{Name='Identity';Expression={$_.Identity.Replace('.com','.com:')}}
```

Your current pipeline object `$_` is a psobject with accessible properties. When you use the dereference operator `.`, you are retrieving a value for one of the properties. `$_.Identity` produces a different object. Since you do not incorporate that value back into a custom object, the only properties you have available are ones available to its object type, which does not include `Identity`.

With that said, you don't technically need to maintain your object schema to perform subsequent tasks. Even if you output a string with your first command, you can store that string in a variable and use it in another command. If your plan is to use a `Foreach-Object` to update all of your objects, you can update the pipelined object for future use within the loop.

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity user@domain.com | ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Identity = $_.Identity.Replace('.com','.com:')
    Remove-MailboxFolderPermissions -Identity $_.Identity -User testuser

}
```